# ReferenceError: spyOnProperty is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

```
it('should update treatment instruction data in UI', async(() => {
     const spy = spyOnProperty(appService.treatmentInstruction, 'next', 
     'get').and.returnValue(treatmentInst);

    component.updateTemplateInUI();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(component.structuresInfo.length).toBe(2);
        expect(component.oarStructureLength).toBe(4);
        expect(component.notesArray.length).toBe(2);
    });
}));
```

ReferenceError: spyOnProperty is not defined error is coming on running test case.

I want to spyOn treatmentInstruction BehaviorSubjectthat is present in my service as mentioned below :

```
treatmentInstruction = new BehaviorSubject(this.myGlobalVar);
currentTreatmentInstruction = this.treatmentInstruction.asObservable();
```

Comment: that should be `spyOn`

Comment: spyOn is for installing spy on function. I want to spyOn on service property of type Observable.

Comment: What is the version of jasmine you are using?

Comment: "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",

Comment: Upgrade to latest version, it should work.

Comment: Thanks  Rakesh Makluri. It worked on upgrading jasmine core version

Comment: can u please help me with access type of BehaviorSubject<T> as it is giving 'Failed: Property next does not have access type get' error

Comment: Are you trying to put a new value into the BehaviorSubject for testing purposes?  If so, simply call `appService.treatmentInstruction.next(treatmentInst)` rather than trying to spy on it...

Comment: Yeah that we can do ... But in unit testing we avoid calling another file function, so wanted to spyOn... please help me with that.

Comment: can we run ng test command when we don't have database connection ? so far i was doing unit test cases with my API and database connection on, while testing i felt during test case execution event after spy my actual database data is coming (found this while debugging). Please correct me whether im doing it right or wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`spyOnProperty` was added on jasmine 2.6.0, be sure that you fulfill that requisite.

Since `jasmine` is a dependency of `karma-jasmine` update that instead. Looks like on old version of this library `jasmine` was added as a [peer dependency](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/blob/b670e886dd/package.json#L40) so it would be up to you to install the correct version of `jasmine`.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade following "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3", "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, updating jasmine version didn't help.
The problem came for jshint, in your test directory you must modify your .jshuntrc file :
in "globals": {
add => "spyOnProperty" : false

Worked for me